# How to connect, through a wireless router, to a subnet, and have the clients join AD domain?

Tags: domain, router, subnet

First I'd describe my subnet A:

- a AD controller, say, adcontroller.mydomain with IP 192.168.1.3
- a DHCP and DNS server, say, dhcpdns.mydomain with IP 192.168.1.10

Now I have a CISCO WRVS4400N wireless router, plug it through WAN port to the switch of subnet A. The router has IP 192.168.1.7 by DHCP of subnet A.

Now I also have several PC/laptops connected to WRVS4400N, and do the following configurations, but I cannot get DHCP IP for these PC/laptops from dhcpdns.mydomain.

- disable DHCP in the router
- configure the router to have static IP in subnet A, say, 192.168.1.7 as before by DHCP. leave the gateway as empty, fill the dns to be 192.168.1.10 (dhcpdns.mydomain).

So, my questions are:

- how to get DHCP IP for these PC/laptops from subnet A, i.e., dhcpdns.mydomain?
- how to join these PC/laptops to the AD domain? I see an option in WRVS4400N configuration page, that is domain name. does this mean the router can join the domain also? how to do the authentication?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By connecting the WAN port on the wireless router to the switch you've segmented your network (you've created two networks).

What you most likely want to do is to connect the LAN port of the wireless router to the switch. The wireless router will then act like a switch (rather than a router) for the wireless clients. The wireless clients will then get their ip configuration from your DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I've only had to disable DHCP on the wireless router in order to allow the DC to assign IP's. My only headache has been BYOD with respect to HTTP/S proxies. The only problem I could see is if you run out of enabled IP's in your DHCP.

Where are you serving up your DHCP?

Comment: do you mean OS by "serve up"? it's a windows 2008 r2 enterprise x64, and the DHCP service is OS built-in (not 3rd party).

Comment: Yep, OS. I would have thought that as long as you have enough available IP's in your DHCP range you should be fine. I'm only an enthusiast however, not a professional in this field. I'd be interested to hear what is actually going on.